# Serilog override settings in appsettings.production with Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I have an issue with serilog when i want to write to a database based on different environments.
Serilog override my appsettings.production.json and always take the settings in appsettings.json instead even in a production mode !

My code in my local **appsettings.json**

```
"Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": {
          "Console" : {"Name": "Console"},
          "Sql": {
             "Name": "MSSqlServer",
             "Args": {
                "connectionString": "Server=MyServerInDev\\SQLSERVER;Database=MyDBDev;user id=ui;password=pw_;ConnectRetryCount=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
                "tableName": "Log",
                "autoCreateSqlTable": true
            }
        }
    },
```

**appsettings.production.json**

```
"Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": {
          "Console" : {"Name": "Console"},
          "Sql": {
             "Name": "MSSqlServer",
             "Args": {
                "connectionString": "Server=MyServerInProd\\SQLSERVER;Database=MyDBProdv;user id=ui;password=pw_;ConnectRetryCount=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
                "tableName": "Log",
                "autoCreateSqlTable": true
            }
        }
    },
```

My **program.cs**

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
```

I am missing something ? and why serilog take the appsettings.json settings and not appsettings.production.json even in prod mode

**Note** that the other settings in the appsettings.production.json work fine. Only the settings in serilog is causing the problem

Comment: Are you sure `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` isn't set to something other than `Production`?

Comment: And that the production config file has been deployed with your app?

Comment: The other settings in the appsettings.production.json work fine. Only the settings in serilog is causing the problem

Comment: I notice that you are adding extra `WriteTo` destinations in the production config, not overriding the dev versions. So it looks like the production version is going to log to 4 places; dev db, production db, and 2 of them are the console.

Comment: @DavidG i updated the ticket but still no log in the database when i am in prod mode, It works only in a dev mode !  I also restarted the pool connection in my production server but no sucess

Comment: well im really confused. Sometimes it works, sometimes not...

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The reason is that Serilog adds sink configs to array, and each of two files of appsettings just adds another sinks instead of replacing them. Solution is explicitly indicate array indexes for each sink. Credits for answer: [nblumhardt](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/70#issuecomment-339812301). Tested, works.

```
"WriteTo": {
  "0": {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "./logs/myapp-.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  }
},
```